# How to import a JSON file from public directory with Vite?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I have a Vue3/Vite project where some data has to be read from an **external JSON** file.

but when i build the project - the JSON file gets bundled.

I need to keep the JSON file external.

What I've tried:

1. first try
   `vite.config.ts`

```js
export default defineConfig({
  optimizeDeps:{
    exclude: ['myfile.json'] // then i tried ['**/myfile.json']
  },
})
```

2. second try

`vite.config.ts`

```js
assetsInclude: ['**/*.json'],
assetsInlineLimit: 0,
```

3. third try

`App.vue`

```js
let jsonData = import.meta.glob('/public/assets/myfile.json')
```

What am I doing wrong - is there a simple way to keep a JSON file external?

Comment: What do you mean by external? You're both trying to exclude + import it in your examples.

Comment: i need to prevent myfile.json from being bundled -> so it can be visible in dist/assets production folder.

Probably example 2 is where you think I try to include it - but the goal there was to inform vite that I need it as a separate asset.

Comment: Not sure to understand. If you DON'T want it bundled, you should store it in `public` directory. If you WANT it to be bundled, then put it in your `src` or `assets` directories. Not sure to understand how you can mix both principles of bundling + keeping as an asset.

Comment: probably you`re right - but the problem with keeping it in public directory is that files in public folder can't be included.

and I need the App to be able to read the JSON content.

Comment: If it's in `public`, you can totally access it. Actually, you can access your JSON from anywhere from within your project tbh.

Comment: include doesn't work - https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory, require neither. so how could i access it otherwise?

Comment: With regular frontend modern `import` pretty much.

Comment: Vite documentation clearly states "Assets in public directory cannot be imported from JavaScript." - and i also encountered errors. Can you please direct me to some resources about "regular frontend modern import" that would do the job?

Comment: "imported from JavaScript" ≠ "imported into JavaScript", I guess the doc means that you cannot generate things on the fly while using runtime? Not sure but it goes in the opposite direction of pretty much anything so far haha (maybe a bug or a super bad wording).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nvm, in Vite you directly use `fetch` to grab the data rather than `import`, which is [not possible](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/8242#discussioncomment-4086368) btw.

This discussion has an [official answer](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/8242#discussioncomment-2790559)

This is how to achieve what you want

```html
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from "vue";

onMounted(async () => {
  const response = await fetch("/file.json");
  const file = await response.json();
  console.log("cool file", file);
});
</script>
```

With the following structure

[image]

`file.json` being

```json
{
  "name": "bob",
  "age": 29
}
```

And with the following result

[image]

Comment: hi this works, but the data wont be updated when updating the json file. This occurs only in the deployed app, not locally runned app.

Comment: @Takkie253 if you run your app as SSR, then you could update the file and read the stream of the filesystem on the fly. Nothing out of bounds of a regular Node.js behavior. If your app is SSG and generated only at build time, then yes it will stay static. You could even do it with a serverless/edge function. Plenty of possibilities there IMO.

Comment: Yeah that explains it, my bad, my app is probably static