# Fetch data from local JSON file with Nuxt Pinia

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, pinia

Is it possible to fetch a local `.json.` file using `fetch()`? I originally used the `import` method but the site's data doesn't get updated unless the page gets reloaded.

I tried doing this but it's not working:

**stores/characters.ts**

```js
export const useCharactersStore = defineStore("characters", {
  state: () => ({
    characters: [],
  }),
  getters: {
    getCharacters: (state) => {
      return state.characters;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    fetchCharacters() {
      fetch("../data.json")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          this.characters = data.characters;
        });
    },
  },
});
```

**app.vue**

```js
import { useCharactersStore } from "~/stores/characters";

const store = useCharactersStore();

onMounted(() => {
  store.fetchCharacters();
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is what APIs are for. fetchCharacters is evaluated on client side, it doesn't make sense for it to be tied to the implementation that can only work on server side

Comment: Give a try to [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74345564/8816585).

Answer (score 1):

maybe a bit late but I have encountered the same problem migrating from Nuxt 2 to Nuxt 3.

I'm certainly no expert on this, so if anyone finds a better way or if I'm totally wrong please let me know !

Whenever you import a json file in vue code they are imported as a module, that get's embedded within the code compilation on build (Vue Docs). To use json as a external file you need to place your json within the /public directory and use axios or fetch to load the file with a lifecyle hook.

*This could be mounted() for options api or beforeMount()/onMounted() with composition api.*

However some important annotations for this method.

If the json file you want to use in your app is not reactive, i.e. won't change, you should place this in the static folder of the nuxt app.

In your example you fetch '../data/...', this would imply the server knows the domain to look for. It can't call the route like this, you would have to give the full url if you put your json file in the static folder.

1. Set the baseUrl in the of your nuxt.config.ts, see docs for specifications.
2. Then you can access the static folder with your .env variables
   --> $fetch

Then in you data script you can access your json file

```
async getJson(some parameters){
const data = $fetch('your domain with the runtimeConfig composable').then((data)=>{ console.log(data)});
```

Sidenote you can also load the file from the server-side using fs.readFile
read more about this in this awesome post [here](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/123)